# Turn a div into a button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

i don't seem to find any way to work this out..so i guess i m going to need some help..
i m making a phonegap application in which i have an sqlite database.I perform a query and get the results in a dynamically created div from the database, the thing is that i want for each record that i extract to make the div that contains it, as a button with an editable role..

for instance lets say that i have a db with these columns id option1 option2 and i have three records..
this means that i will have three divs
i want, each div to be a button so that if user clicks on it to be able to perform a delete (or edit/update) query without being worried about id
for instance, if he selects div2 do perform a query that will delete second record..

my code so far..

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var test1 = results.rows.item(i).option1;
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(results.rows.item(i).date);
    var newLI = document.createElement("LI");
    newLI.className = lt;
    newLI.id = results.rows.item(i).id;
    var container = ("<div id=\"" + results.rows.item(i).id + "\" class=\"test\"><div id=\"text\">option1</div><div id=\"data\">" + test1 + "</div></div>");
    newLI.innerHTML = cont;
    var gl = document.getElementById("sqltest");
    gl.appendChild(newLI);
}
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var divid = "#" + results.rows.item(i).id;
    $(divid).on("click", function () {
        alert(divid);
    })
}

<ul id="sqltest"></ul>
```

problem with above code, is that although each div gets the correct id, when i click on it, i always get the same result for instance #1 although i may have 3 divs..
instead of having as a result

```
div1 alert #1 div2 alert #2
```

i get

```
div1 alert #1 div2 alert#1
```

I've used alert just to simplify it, instead of alert there will be `DELETE from SQLDB WHERE id=results.rows.item(i).id;`

Comment: U could aways replace the html with the html for a button?

Comment: the div does become clickable..however the weird thing is, that although all i.e. 3 divs become clickable,  and means that at the divid does targets the correct div, when alerted, it returns wrong value..

Comment: oh, i didn't read the question right, you always could alert all the variables, and see what the code is doing? This usually helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retreiving always the same 'divid' variable, because of the way javascript scope and closures work. This is a very common mistake. You can google "javascript closure infamous loop" to get more information about this.

You should replace your *for* with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    (function () {
        var divid = "#" + results.rows.item(i).id;
        $(divid).on("click", function () {
            alert(divid);
        });
    })();
}
```

That way, the variable *divid* is declared in different scopes each time.

I didn't understand if that is the only problem you are having.

Comment: after taking some rest, i realised what i was doing wrong, but haven't figure how to solve it.. the $(divid) was getting the correct value, but probably the alert was taking the wrong one, because the alert is, within the function, so it is exectued, actually after the loop is over and when the button is pressed..so it is reasonable to have wrong alert value..i ll try your example to see if thsat fixed it.. but i think that this is not the only problem that i m having afterall..

Comment: update...it doesn't do the trick after all... :S

if i call second time the function, then the divid variable holds the previous value as well...:S

Comment: Wich function are you calling? You can click any number of times the div, and it will always alert its id. Please be more specific so I can help you.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply Pato..your code does help a lot, but as you predicted, the problem differed in some way.. i started another thead here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869663/javascript-keeps-looping with the new aspect of the problem..i would really appreciate if you cold help.. does stackoverflow support private msg?