# javascript keeps looping

Tags: javascript, cordova, for-loop, scope

continuing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850823/turn-a-div-into-a-button-dynamically) ... since the problem has signifally altered (in my opinion)

here is my code

```
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            (function () {
                var queryid = results.rows.item(i).id; //sql primary key
                var divid = "#" + queryid; //assigned id to divs
                var pressTimer;
                $(divid).mouseup(function(){ //func to handle tap + hold
                clearTimeout(pressTimer)
                // Clear timeout
                return false;
                }).mousedown(function(){
                // Set timeout
                pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
                alert(divid);
                $(".somediv").show();
                $("#anotherdiv").hide();
                $("#button").on("click", function(){
                    var db = window.openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "mydb", 200000);
                    db.transaction(editrow);    
                    function editrow(tx){
                        var value1 = $("#inputbox1").val();
                        var value2 = $("#inputbox2").val();
                        tx.executeSql("UPDATE mydb SET column1 = " + value1 + ", column2 = " + value2 + " WHERE id = " + queryid);
                        alert(divid); ********
                        successCB();} //query function
                })
                },1000)
                return false; 
                });
                })();
            }
```

if i click on the div and i edit the values, they are submitted successfully...
however, if after that i select another div to update its fields, then the new value is updated both to selected div, as well as to the previous selected div..

for instance i select div1 and update the values everything is ok

if after that i select div2 then both div1 and div2 values are update with more recent values for div2

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with *setTimeout*. Do you want the *#button* to do an update on the last clicked div? It must be pressed for an entire second?

Comment: the setTimeout is just to trigger the div(button) to proceed with its events, after prolonged tapping on the screen..
since i m making this for smart phone, i dont want this specific action to be triggered on click, but on click + hold..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the events more than once. In every mousedown on the div, you are binding a click event to the button. You are not **asigning** the event handler when you call "on" or "click" in jquery, you are **adding** a handler.

I didn't understand if you need the call to setTimeout.

Try this aproach insted:

```
var lastClickedId = null;
function editrow(tx) {
    var value1 = $("#inputbox1").val();
    var value2 = $("#inputbox2").val();
    var queryid = lastClickedId;
    tx.executeSql("UPDATE mydb SET column1 = " + value1 + ", column2 = " + value2 + " WHERE id = " + queryid);
    alert(queryid);
    lastClickedId = null;

    successCB();
} //query function

$("#button").on("click", function(){

    if(lastClickedId != null)
    {
        var db = window.openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "mydb", 200000);
        db.transaction(editrow);
    }
});

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    (function () {
        var queryid = results.rows.item(i).id; //sql primary key
        var divid = "#" + queryid; //assigned id to divs

        $(divid).click(function(){
            lastClickedId = queryid;
        });
    })();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

When you bind elements in jquery using *bind(func)*, *on(func)*, *click(func)*, etc, you are registering the function *func* to be called whenever the event ocurrs. You can register any number of functions. So, for example, if you do:

```
$("#div1").on("click", function() { alert("hello"); });
$("#div1").on("click", function() { alert("world"); });
```

It will display two alerts when you click. This is because of the way jquery manages events. It calls every function you passed in the event.

To detach all the clicks events you atached to that element (or elements) with *on*, just do:

```
$("#div1").off("click");
```

In "pure" javascript you can do this:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

div1.onclick = function() { alert("hello"); };
div1.onclick = function() { alert("world"); };
```

And in this second example, only one alert will be called, because you are directly asigning a value to the function onclick.
And to remove the event:

```
div1.onclick = null;
```

Comment: hi Pato, i tried it including the code with mouseup/down..and it really seems to work ok..(i think all trick is done successfully by lastClickedId variable...and if statement about it whether it is null or not.. :)
 i ve been a little bit confused about binding click event and assigning click event and adding handler..but i don't know if you have the time to comment a little bit further on these..to really understand what is going on and what is wrong/bad practice..

Comment: It was really helpful Palo.. Thank you very much i really appreciate it :-)